# Date Time Format String only for Milliseconds

Tags: c#

for a Project i parse timestamps from filenames and each has its own format. I get the files from a partner company, so the naming of the files is non negotiable. The problem now is, that besides one, every filename has a nice time format that can easily be transferred to a c# date time format string to be parsed into a DateTime object. The one that differs, strictly uses milliseconds since initialization as it's timestamp similar to
`+4311123234_12345 M.txt` where the numbers after the underscore are said milliseconds.

In this example the milliseconds would be `12345` but a filename could also be `+4311123234_123423402345802345 M.txt` where `123423402345802345` would be said milliseconds. To me only the milliseconds part is relevant and is extracted from the filename. I now want a string such as "yyyy" (for year typically) where this number is then parsed to a DateTime Object via the `TryParseExact` method. It is not important from when the milliseconds are counted, since it is just used for sorting so for all i care they can be the milliseconds elapsed since 01.01.1900 00:00:00.

I did a google search but came to the conclusion, that such a date time format string doesn't really exist. I know that there is `ss.fffff` but since i do not know how many digits the millisecond timestamp has, i would have to generate a seperate formatstring with the according number of 'f's. This is also no option, because the format string should be a user input.

Right now i coupled it to a special keyword, so that when the input is `keyword` the time will not be parsed by a timeformatstring but simply by the milliseconds that i got from parsing the section in the filename to a long.
It works fine, but it really isn't ideal in my opinion...
What i forgot to say was, that the string containing the timestamp is extracted from the filename via Regex CaptureGroups, so in the code example the timestampstring is in `cc[0]`

```
private static void CheckForValidMatch(SortedList<DateTime, string> files, string file, Match match,string dateTimeFormat,int groupNumber)
        {
            Group group = match.Groups[groupNumber];
            CaptureCollection cc = group.Captures;
            DateTime dateTime;
            if (cc.Count == 0)
                Debug.WriteLine("group did not capture anything");
            else
            {
                if (dateTimeFormat.Equals("keyword"))
                {
                    if (long.TryParse(cc[0].ToString(),out var result))
                    {
                        dateTime = new DateTime(result);
                        files.Add(dateTime, file);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(cc[0].ToString(),dateTimeFormat,DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo,DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dateTime))
                    Debug.WriteLine("parsing the date time failed");
                else
                {
                    files.Add(dateTime, file);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to make this more elegant, or does someone know a formatstring only for milliseconds?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give some examples of these filenames and the expected results. For the one input (i.e. `+4311123234_12345 M.txt`) show in the question it is not clear what the two numbers (`4311123234` and `12345`) mean and how you want them treated.

Comment: Yes examples pls. You wrote a lot of fluffy prose, but we actually need concise examples of inputs and expected outputs in order to help you.

Comment: For instance that "milliseconds", is that just the millisecond part of a regular datetime value (so between 0 and 1000), or "milliseconds since 1970-01-01" (or some other fixed date)

Comment: what i specifically want is to parse a string containing a number of unspecified length to a `DateTime` Object via the `TryParseExact` method, it is not a problem if it is impossible but i was just searching for a prettier option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect to parse it directly as a datetime. Instead, keep a constant `epoch` DateTime value for the base date, parse the file name as a `long`, and then do this:

```
var FileDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(parsedLongValue);
```

So we get this:

```
private static void CheckForValidMatch(SortedList<DateTime, string> files, string file, Match match,string dateTimeFormat,int groupNumber)
{    
    var cc = match.Groups[groupNumber].Captures;   
    if (cc.Count == 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("group did not capture anything");
        return;
    }

    DateTime dateTime;
    if (dateTimeFormat == "keyword")
    {    
        // I don't know your epoch date, but Jan 1, 1970 is common (it's the unix epoch)
        const DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);   
        if (long.TryParse(cc[0].ToString(),out var result))
        {
            dateTime = epoch.AddMilliseconds(result);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"parsing the date time for {dateTimeormat} failed");
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(cc[0].ToString(),dateTimeFormat,DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo,DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dateTime))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("parsing the date time failed");
        return;
    }

    files.Add(dateTime, file);    
}
```